# extract text from regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am new with regular expressions. I want to extract timestamp value from this text

```
chunk =['leaset loaded server= 10, timestamp= 1494370749.94']
try:
     found = re.findall('\['+'+ timestamp= +'+'\]', chunk).group(1)
  except AttributeError:

     found = 'Not found'
```

this gave me not found. what is the correct statement for extracting it.

Comment: Do you only want to extract the string 'timestamp=', or do you want to extract the value of timestamp as well?

Comment: try `re.findall(r'(?<=timestamp= ).*?(?=\'])', chunk)[0]`

Comment: You show an unnamed list and something called `chunk` - what is that? It should be easy to turn this into a running example. You also haven't mentioned what went wrong.

Comment: @downshift I tried your solution but it gave me IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up `findall` and `search`. While you could write it either way, `search` will stop after it finds the string and so its a bit faster.

```
>>> import re
>>> chunk = 'leaset loaded server= 10, timestamp= 1494370749.94'
>>> match = re.search(r'timestamp= ([\d\.]+)', chunk)
>>> if match:
...     print(match.group(1))
... 
1494370749.94
```

Comment: chunk is list, so when I tried this it gave me TypeError: expected string or buffer and when I used match = re.search(r'timestamp= ([\d\.]+)', str(chunk)) it gave me <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fc070cf4c60>